# Delete specific cache in Flask-Cache or Flask-Caching

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-cache, flask-caching

I am using Flask cache in my API in python.

Currently I am using the decorator `@app.cache.memoize(cache_memoize_value)` and I flush it by calling `app.cache.delete_memoized(view)`

The problem is that with `memoize` it will be cached for `n` views and not for a specific amount of time. If I want to specify a timeout for the cache I need to use the decorator `@app.cache.cached(timeout=300)` and clear it with `app.cache.clear()`. However, this clear method will clear everything and not only a specific view.

How can I only clear a specific view while using the cached decorator?

Comment: In fact, I got same problem. There is function, `delete`, but the api says `
delete(*args, **kwargs)

    Proxy function for internal cache object.
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in fact pretty easy and I should have tried this before.
Like for the cached decorator, you can specify a value in the memoized decorator.
But instead of doing this:
`@app.cache.memoize(cache_memoize_value)`

You need to do this 
`@app.cache.memoize(timeout=cache_memoize_value)`

Comment: Do you know how to `delete` a spercific cache, if I want to cache the views

Comment: Just use `cache.delete_memoized(function_with_cache_memoize_decorator, param1, param2)` within another function than function_with_cache_memoize_decorator.

Answer (score 12):

- For `cache.cached()`, use `cache.delete()` to delete specific cache, pass the cache key (default to `view/<request.path>`).
- For `cache.memoize()`, use `cache.delete_memoized()` to delete specific cache, pass the cache key (default to function name with or without args).
- Use `cache.clear()` to delete all the cache data.

Comment: I would add for future reference, if you need to delete a particular cached value, you can do it like this:
`cache.delete_memoized(function_with_cache_decorator, value_to_delete)`